# Winetricks not in dash or menu - Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, wine, unity-dash, menu, winetricks

I installed new Ubuntu 13.04 and Wine 1.5.29 trough ppa. But I noticed that on older Ubuntu versions, after installation of wine and winetricks (they install together now), there is a "Winetricks" icon in the menu (Cairo dock) and in the dash.
On Ubuntu 13.04, after successful installation of both, there is NO "winetricks" in dash or the menu.
It works trough terminal command normally but I want the dash icon (I'm a new user, used to "point and click"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the terminal to add an application shortcut. You'll only have to do this once and it's fairly easy.

Open up a terminal window by searching for "Terminal" or pressing Ctrl+Shift+T.

Type in the following:

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/winetricks.desktop
```

This will open a text editor.

Copy and paste in the following into the terminal window:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Winetricks
Comment=Wine Package Manager
Exec=winetricks --gui
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Applications
Comment[en_GB]=Wine Package Manager
```

Then press Ctrl+O then enter to save it. Now press Ctrl+X to exit.

The last thing you'll need to do is to make it executable. To do this, type the following:

```
chmod 777 ~/.local/share/applications/winetricks.desktop
```

Done. Now when you look for "Winetricks" in the Unity search lens, it will appear. The icon will be a blank page.

Edit:
You can put this winetricks.desktop wherever you want, you could make the file in gedit then right click > properties > allow executing file as program. Then you can put it where you want and double click it to run it.

Comment: It works but the shame is that the icon dosen appears

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal you can run:

```
winetricks --gui
```

Comment: As I said, it works trough terminal but I would like an icon on the menu like in ubuntu 12.04.